# How to clear a third-party cache when Craft updates its own template caches

Tags: caching

We're experimenting with using [Fastly](http://fastly.com) for full-site caching of a Craft site. Everything is working great so far, with the exception that Fastly obviously has no way to know when a URL's cache has been invalidated.

We were thinking that the easiest way to make this work would be to use Craft's built-in caching and create a simple plugin that listens for Craft to invalidate a URL's cache (such as when updating an Entry referenced by that cache) and call out to Fastly to clear its cache for the same URL.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, Craft doesn't provide an Event for when it updates its own caches. Am I missing something? Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: This actually sounds like a feature request to me. There aren't any [native events](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) which notify of caching events, though it's reasonable to put in an official feature request for P&T to add them. I can't think of a non-events based way to handle this, but we'll leave this question open a little longer in case anyone comes up with a good workaround.

Comment: I don't know of any clever workarounds, but this is on our 2.2 list to add events so that 3rd party services can be notified when template caches get invalidated.

Comment: Thanks Lindsey and Brad. I'll just look forward to 2.2 and figure out another solution to this for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of any clever workarounds, but this is on our 2.2 list to add events so that 3rd party services can be notified when template caches get invalidated.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer for now, and I'll update the question when 2.2 is released. In the meantime, we created a simple plugin that listens for the `onSaveEntry` event and call out to Fastly to purge its entire cache. It's brute force but its simple and works until the cache invalidation event is available.

Comment: Any update on this? Is this something we should expect in v3?